# Code for Autoinstallation of android app like Plan B App in android market?

Tags: android, installation

We have developed an App, we want to autoinstall it on users Android phone just like Plan B App which installs the app even if the mobile is lost and helps in recovering it.

Any Help in writing code appreciated

Comment: We dont know where to start? Has been googling found articles explaining Remote installation http://www.talkandroid.com/4691-android-os-allows-remote-installation-too/ , but not how to do it

Answer (score 2):

> we want to autoinstall it on users Android phone just like Plan B App which installs the app even if the mobile is lost and helps in recovering it

Plan B does not do this.

First, Plan B does not "installs the app even if the mobile is lost". That is not possible. If the user loses their device *and* their Google account is still configured on their device, the *user* can go into the Play Store on the Web and still install apps on their now-missing device. You as a developer are not involved in this process.

What Plan B used to be able to do was automatically get control after some period of time, without user intervention. Fortunately, this is no longer possible as of Android 3.1, as it was a popular technique among malware authors.